# devise + omniauth logout

Tags: facebook, devise, omniauth, logout

I finally got "sign in with Facebook" to work with devise/omniauth, but when a user is signed in, the "sign in with facebook" link doesn't change to "sign out" and/or there is no visible sign out option.

here is my route.rb file

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => 'registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout' } do
  get 'login' =>'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  get 'signup'  => 'registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
  get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```

end

and here is the user file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=ni)
user = User.where (:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
unless user

def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
user = User.where
user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                     provider:auth.provider,
                     uid:auth.uid,
                     email:auth.info.email,
                     password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                     )
end
user
end

end
```

session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def create
 user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
 session[:user_id] = user.id
 redirect_to root_path
 end

def destroy
 session.delete[:user_id] = nil
 redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

Omniauth_callbacks_controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
# You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not       activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
end
```

and lastly, the application layout

```
<% if current_user %>
      Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
      <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session, id: "sign_out" %>
    <% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></li>
  <% end %>
```

Not quite sure waht i keep doing wrong or why I'm having a hard time looking for the answer, so I thought it might be easier to just put up the code. I"m new at this, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will you post your users/omniauth_callbacks controller?

Comment: `class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)**

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end`

Comment: If you could please edit your original answer, and add this code to the bottom that would be much better. Also, please include your User model since that is being called by the User::OmniauthCallbackController

Comment: gotcha, updated! this is a really basic question, but where would i find the user model?

Comment: You will find models located in app/models, so the user model will be in app/models/user.rb

Comment: ok, the user model is the second set of code above--i think the ominiauth part of this is working, since it connects to facebook--maybe it's something about how omniauth is working with devise that is the problem? am i to have devise set up separately when running omniauth + devise? i didn't do that bc the omniauth git wiki didn't mention that i had to do that...

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer - current_user is nil so your not actually logged in.

If "Sign in with Facebook" is still showing, and Sign Out is not showing, i'm assuming the "Signed in as" Is also not showing.

This is most likely due to this current_user not being set, so this line is failing

```
<% if current_user %>
```

and so this code gets triggered

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></li>
```

So I am assuming current_user is not actually getting set, therefore you're not really logged in. You can add the devise controller filter `authenticate_user!` to see if you're logged in or not. Something like

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Which will redirect you if you are not logged in.

### Use Pry To Find Out

[Pry](http://rubygems.org/gems/pry) is a great tool for debugging these kinds of things

To debug with pry, you would add to your Gemfile

```
group :development do
  gem "pry", "~> 0.9.12.4"
end
```

and run `bundle install`

you can then add this to your code

```
<%= binding.pry %>
<% if current_user %>
  Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session, id: "sign_out" %>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Go through your normal Login with Facebook workflow, and the Rails Server in your terminal will 'stop' at the `<% binding.pry %> and allow you to run commands, including checking variables.

In the terminal your rails console is running in, you should see something like

```
current_user ? "There is a current user set" : "No current user is set"
```

You may also just run

```
current_user
```

but the former has more verbose output. Some other useful debugging commands include

`help` 
`whereami` 
`exit`
`!!!`

Comment: thanks for your response, @ruevaughn! well, so when i first logged in, it took me to facebook to verify and authenticate that i wanted to log in with facebook...so does that mean it worked or didn't work? how do i set the user then if it isn't set?

Comment: That screen means you configured everything correctly to talk to facebook, but doesn't mean that everything went flush after. I'm thinking you have a syntax error in your User::OmniauthCallbacksController, probably around here:   User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)**

Comment: sign_in_and_redirect @user is what should be signing your in, and setting current_user